Can a bluetooth audio device (headset) send key events similar to an input device?
I downloaded an app on my android device that reads key events called KeyEvent Display. The app can detect key events from an external bluetooth keyboard. I have a few questions:

When I press the media buttons from the keyboard, the buttons work and the app correctly detects them, for example for media next it shows code 87. But when I press the media next button on the headset, although the button work the app doesn't detect them, as if no button was pressed. Why is that?

When I press the brightness up and brightness down keys or the launcher key from the external bluetooth keyboard the keys work, i.e. the brightness on the phone goes up and down, but the app doesn't show any key event, why could that be?

Can a bluetooth audio device sent other key events besides the standard media buttons, for example brightness up, brightness down, space bar, characters etc, similar to the key events by an external bluetooth keyboard? Or only bluetooth keyboard input devices can do that?


